# Permissions Different in SQLCMD and SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms, sqlcmd

In both cases, I'm logged in using Windows Authentication. My account is a Domain account with the sysadmin role on the SQL Server (2005). I've even verified my sid is the same, by querying SUSER_SID().

The following query returns 1, indicating I do have permission to the database when run from SSMS, but 0 when run from SQLCMD

```
select HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('<user_database>', 'DATABASE', 'ANY')
```

Replace `<user_database>` above with the name of any user database. Oddly, if I try this with one of the MS databases (master, model, msdb), it works.

The exact command I'm using for SQLCMD is the following:

```
sqlcmd -E -s<server> -d<database> -Q"select HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('<user_database>', 'DATABASE', 'ANY')"
```

I'm trying to chase down a problem where my login to the database is failing from SQLCMD and succeeds from SSMS. I believe that I can get this to work by creating a SQL Server login and using SQL Server authentication, but I'd rather not go that route.

Comment: Is there any chance the connection context from SSIS is getting changed dynamically at run time?  Perhaps try this from both SSMS and SQLCMD to compare:  `SELECT @@SERVERNAME, DB_Name(), SYSTEM_USER`

Comment: Actually, that helped. I'm such an idiot. 

-s vs. -S on the SQLCMD command line.

The command should be sqlcmd -E -S<server> not -s<server>

I missed that typo for hours.

Everything is working now.

Comment: Glad that helped.  I missed the `S` vs `s` switch too.  I guess before the fix, SQLCMD was connecting to your local instance of MSSQL.